# VBA CSV file has missing data from excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am learning VBA and have come across a problem where data from a formula are blank in the created CSV file.

I have a macro that updates data and then runs solver to get a solution and I would like to store the result set as a CSV file for further processing. It all works with the exception that some numeric data is not pasted into the CSV. The missing data is calculated via a formula, I have tested with manually entered data and this works. I have tried using pastespecial xlPasteValues but I get an error

Run Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Private Sub cmdSave()
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim WB As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    sFileName = "PhotoRunPlan.csv"
    'Copy the contents of required sheet ready to paste into the new CSV
    Sheets(1).Range("Runplan").Copy 'Define your own range

    'Open a new XLS workbook, save it as the file name
    Set WB = Workbooks.Add
    With WB
        .Title = "MyTitle"
        .Subject = "MySubject"
        .Sheets(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs "C:\Users\rtovey1\Documents\1401 - Photo Optimiser\RunPlan\" & sFileName, xlCSV
        .Close
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You don't use

```
 ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

but use a Range, example:

```
.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z1000").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\rtovey1\Documents\1401 - Photo Optimiser\RunPlan\" & sFileName, xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

This will save a copy of the activesheet as a csv. No need to copy/paste/open new workbooks.